# Using submit_form in rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have tried to scrape a website for data. Below is a simpliefied version of the script I am using. In this example the *disease.table* retreived by html_table in the last line should include all the years from 2014 to 2017. Currently, it only contains 2017.

```
# Initiate wahis.session website session.
url <- "http://www.oie.int/wahis_2/public/wahid.php/Diseaseinformation/statusdetail"
wahis.session <- html_session(url)

# Get forms with searchable fields in current session.
form <- html_form(wahis.session)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Fill out and submit forms

# First, Copy form.
filled.form <- form

# Set values in form #3
filled.form[[3]] <- set_values(filled.form[[3]],
                               selected_start_year = "2014") # start year
# Set form url to empty character string to prevent error message when
# submitting.
filled.form[[3]]$url <- ""

# Submit form #3
submit_form(session = wahis.session,
        form = filled.form[[3]],
        submit = 'disease_id_terrestrial')

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Retreive data

# Find data table
disease.table <- wahis.session %>%
  html_node("div.OverflowAutoScroll table.TableFoyers") %>%
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer. The `submit_form()` function needs to be applied to the active html session. Submitting the form using the following code worked:

```
# Submit form #3
wahis.session <- submit_form(session = wahis.session,
        form = filled.form[[3]],
        submit = 'disease_id_terrestrial'
```

No other changes were needed.